# will this part of the code be executed in the merge sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

The algorithm for merge sort is

> Step 1 − if it is only one element in the list it is already sorted, return.
>   Step 2 − divide the list recursively into two halves until it can no more be divided.
>   Step 3 − merge the smaller lists into new list in sorted order.

with this psedu code:

```
procedure mergesort( var a as array )
   if ( n == 1 ) return a

   var l1 as array = a[0] ... a[n/2]
   var l2 as array = a[n/2+1] ... a[n]

   l1 = mergesort( l1 )
   l2 = mergesort( l2 )

   return merge( l1, l2 )
end procedure

procedure merge( var a as array, var b as array )

   var c as array

   while ( a and b have elements )
      if ( a[0] > b[0] )
         add b[0] to the end of c
         remove b[0] from b
      else
         add a[0] to the end of c
         remove a[0] from a
      end if
   end while

   while ( a has elements )
      add a[0] to the end of c
      remove a[0] from a
   end while

   while ( b has elements )
      add b[0] to the end of c
      remove b[0] from b
   end while

   return c

end procedure
```

my question is:

in the **merge** function, there are two while loop to check if `a` and `b` still have items and adding them to the `c` array.

my quesion is will (could) these two **whiles** be executed in the same function?

or like if `a` still have items, that means `b` is definately empty and vise versa?

Comment: why guys you are minuse me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If both of them were still not empty than the first while condition would have been true.

After the first while has finished, at least one of a, b is empty.